# How to use dynamic import in NextJS to import an SDK

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use this WebcamSDK, which works in React but not NextJS

The SDK contains different exports that look like this

```
//@/component/sdk/WebcamSDK.js
export class Webcam {...}
export class Player {...}
export class Dom {...}
```

in my component I have:

```
//only load Webcam when there's a browser present
const WebcamAssets = dynamic(() => import("@/components/sdk/WebcamSDK"), {
  ssr: false
});
...
const Meeting = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
       ...
       const { Webcam, Player, Dom } = WebcamAssets; 
    })

}
```

The above code does not work, but when I do pure react import like this, it works fine

```
import { Webcam, Player, Dom } from "path/to/SDK/WebcamSDK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NextJS 'next/dynamic' module is made for components.

Try `await import()`:

```
const Meeting = async () => {
    useEffect(() => {
       ...
       const { Webcam, Player, Dom } = await import("@/components/sdk/WebcamSDK"); 
    })

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either. await is just awaiting for the import, which will be rendered on SSR and it doesn't wait until it's on client side. This produced `ReferenceError: screen is not defined`

Comment: It won't be rendered on SSR. All code that placed inside `useEffect` will be always executed on client-side

Comment: What is `screen` btw? Where it comes from?

Comment: yeah you're right, it rendered, but I could not extract the components for some reason. I had an error the first time bc I had it defined twice. I think screen was coming from the fact that it was server side so it was not seeing client side screen.

Comment: What kind of code includes 'WebcamSDK'. Because what I can see that importing actually works as expected. The problem is in different

Comment: So what is the current state of the issue? What can you see in console?

Comment: it still doesn't extract the components `Webcam, Player, Dom` with the import await above

Comment: if you try import().then(result => console.log(result)); what will be in console?

Comment: Could you please insert some file structure of the `WebcamSDK` in the question body pls?. Because I can feel that we are close to solve the problem, but I still don't see whole picture

Comment: @guest One more remark. Always add dependency array to your useEffect hooks, otherwise hook executes on each re-render (component did update). Do `useEffect(..., [])` which means component did mount.

Comment: yes, thanks! I did. What happened earlier is not sure. When I killed the app and restarted it again, it worked.

Comment: @guest Yeah, sometimes that happens to me. After some critical errors or huge refactoring I always do a restart

Comment: Btw, how do you use the import variables from import outside of useEffect? I tried to manage it via useState inside the component, but it doesn't seem to save. this is another weird thing to me. the imports are undefined when used outside of useEffect (even though the state vars are defined outside of useState) @Max

Comment: @guest That is how SSR works in NextJS. To build initial HTML page, NextJS build every component on server-side, then the hydration comes in. Which make HTML to React app. So useEffect is using to encapsulate code running only on client-side.

Actuall you can all `let import1, improt2, import3;` outside the component and assign imports to them when ready. But for more accurate answer I would like to know why you want to do that

Comment: it has to do with managing webcam and video players. i don't want to create instances of the multiple players, managing them via event clicks/actions. I only want 1 import instance. I ended up just import and creating 1 instances of webcam, re-using it, rather than saving the imports in useState.

Comment: @guest It seems `let` imports outside the component may be a solution

Comment: cool! you've been so helpful. would love to connect with you offline since we're in the same space

Comment: @guest Where are you from?